# (ReactJS) Error when looping nested array to create table data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, datatable

I'm getting stuck here.
I have the data like below:

```
const dummyData= [
    {
        brand: 'volcom',
        first_stock_amount: 100,
        total_income: 20,
        total_expend: 5,
        final_stock_amount: 7,
        expend: [{
            out_date: 1,
            out_amount:2,
        }]
    },
     {
        brand: 'billabong',
         first_stock_amount: 300,
         total_income: 10,
         total_expend: 5,
         final_stock_amount: 7,
        expend: [{
            out_date: 2,
            out_amount:3
        }]
    },
     {
       brand: 'ripcurl',
         first_stock_amount: 200,
         total_income: 5,
         total_expend: 5,
         final_stock_amount: 7,
        expend: [{
            out_date: 3,
            out_amount:4
        }]
    },
];
```

When I rendered it to create table it works just fine.

The result is like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 <Table size="sm" hover responsive bordered>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th rowSpan={2}>NO</th>
                            <th rowSpan={2}>BRAND</th>
                            <th rowSpan={2}>FIRST STOCK AMOUNT</th>
                            <th rowSpan={2}>TOTAL INCOME</th>
                            <th colSpan={31}>EXPEND</th>
                            <th rowSpan={2}>TOTAL EXPEND</th>
                            <th rowSpan={2}>FINAL STOCK AMOUNT</th>
                        </tr>
                        {this.createTableDate()}
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {dummyData.map((row, index) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={`row-${index}`}>
                                    <td>
                                        {index + 1}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{row.brand}</td>
                                    <td>{row.first_stock_amount}</td>
                                    <td />
                                    {row.expend.map(childRow => {
                                        return (
                                            this.state.daysInMonth.map((a, i) => {
                                                if (a == childRow.out_date) {
                                                    return <td key={`row-child-${a}`}>
                                                        {childRow.out_amount}
                                                    </td>
                                                } else {
                                                    return <td key={`row-child-${a}`}>
                                                        0
                                                    </td>
                                                }
                                            })

                                        )
                                    })}
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
```

but when I add a new data to expend in dummyData

```
dummyData= [
    {
        brand: 'volcom',
        first_stock_amount: 100,
        total_income: 20,
        total_expend: 5,
        final_stock_amount: 7,
        expend: [{
            out_date: 1,
            out_amount:2,
        },
{
            out_date: 2,
            out_amount:3,
        }]
    },
     {
        brand: 'billabong',
         first_stock_amount: 300,
         total_income: 10,
         total_expend: 5,
         final_stock_amount: 7,
        expend: [{
            out_date: 2,
            out_amount:3
        }]
    },
     {
       brand: 'ripcurl',
         first_stock_amount: 200,
         total_income: 5,
         total_expend: 5,
         final_stock_amount: 7,
        expend: [{
            out_date: 3,
            out_amount:4
        }]
    },
];
```

an error happened.. it's not rendered as per date, but creating like a new cell to the side..

[image]

what's wrong here?
Maybe its asking before but I cannot find what I'm looking for.

[Here is the codesandbox I made](https://codesandbox.io/s/vw7wzwvr7)

Comment: 1) Please put your code to https://jsfiddle.net/ 2) Make keys at `expand.map()` different. Like `key={\`row-child-${a}_out_date\`}` and `key={\`row-child-${a}\`}`

Comment: @SLCH000 https://codesandbox.io/s/vw7wzwvr7, done. I already change the key too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how your code should work.

You write 31 `<td />`s the amount of time the number of items in `expend` is. Try rendering `dummyData` with `expend = []`

Here is the code with fixed logic and fixed keys https://codesandbox.io/s/88k5ynyqy9

Comment: wow!! thank you so much!!! it's work, so it have to render the data with expend. I see, try to understand ur code now hehe..